# Vue select with deep nested data

Tags: vue.js, vue-select

I'm trying to make a v-select according to instruction on official documentation but my data is more nested than it shown in documentation,  i can not show in my v-select the **llcName** of my data, and i'm stuck with this.

This is my html div and Vue instance with data below

```
<div id="vs">
  <h1>Vue Select</h1>
  <v-select multiple :options="options" :reduce="node=>  node.llcName" label='llcName' v-model='selected' />
  <pre>[[$data]]</pre>
</div>

<script>


Vue.component('v-select', VueSelect.VueSelect)

new Vue({
  el: '#vs',
  delimiters: ["[[", "]]"],
  data: {
    options: [
    {
      "node": {
        "id": "U3VwcGxpZXJPYmplY3Q6MzA1",
        "llcName": "new",
        "suppPayment": {
          "edges": [0]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "node": {
        "id": "U3VwcGxpZXJPYmplY3Q6MzA2",
        "llcName": "new2",
        "suppPayment": {
          "edges": [1]
        }

      }
    },
    {
      "node": {
        "id": "U3VwcGxpZXJPYmplY3Q6MzA3",
        "llcName": "rteer",
        "suppPayment": {
          "edges": [2]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
    selected:"",
  }
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should use [getOptionLabel](https://vue-select.org/api/props.html#getoptionlabel) instead of `label` and there is a mistake in your `reduce` property.

```html
<v-select
  multiple
  v-model='selected'
  :options='options'
  :get-option-label='option => option.node.llcName'
  :reduce='option => option.node.llcName'/>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f560pLqz/)